# Radio Button Change Event JavaFx

Tags: events, javafx, radio-button, onchange, radio-group

i have a lot of HBoxes with some different components inside ( RadioButton, Labels, Buttons ...).
The RadioButtons are in a ToggleGroup, so only 1 Radio Button can be selected.

I want to add a OnChange - Event to the Radio Button. If the RadioButton would be unselected there should be a Event-Trigger. How can i add the Event to the Radio-Button?

At the moment i have a code like this, but it doesn't have the function i want to have.

```
radio.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(!radio.isSelected()){
                ivTriangleImg.setRotate(iRotateCoord2);
                btnTriangle.setGraphic(ivTriangleImg);
            }

            if(group!=null){
                group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {

                    @Override
                    public void changed(
                            ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> arg0,
                            Toggle arg1, Toggle arg2) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I use JavaFX 2.0 and Java 1.7 so i can not use Lambda Functions or the special component functions of JavaFx8 / Java 1.8

Comment: **group=Toggle Group**
I want to get the information when the Radio >Button is not selected...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
radio.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(!radio.isSelected()){
                ivTriangleImg.setRotate(iRotateCoord2);
                btnTriangle.setGraphic(ivTriangleImg);
            }

            if(group!=null){
                group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {

                    @Override
                    public void changed(
                            ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> arg0,
                            Toggle arg1, Toggle arg2) {

                        if(!radio.isSelected()&&ivTriangleImg.getRotate()!=iRotateCoord1){
                            ivTriangleImg.setRotate(iRotateCoord1);
                            btnTriangle.setGraphic(ivTriangleImg);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

This would work for my Question. I have done a little mistake, so i don't check the Radio-Style. It works fine now... Sorry for this Question.

**Is there a possibility to check the Event at the Radio Button and not at his group?**

Comment: It's been a long time :) But: don't quite understand the bolded text at the bottom - is it another question, or another formulation of the original question? Anyway, all you do seems to be rotating the graphic based on its selection state. If so, css or binding might be another approach.

Answer (score 7):

The state of JavaFX controls is represented by observable properties. You can access these properties with `control.propertyNameProperty()` and [add `ChangeListener`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-) to them:

```
radioButton.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean wasPreviouslySelected, Boolean isNowSelected) {
        if (isNowSelected) { 
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you have many radio buttons you dont want have a single EventHandlers for each one of them....

Here is an example with 6 radio buttons but just one ChangeListener where the events are all process in a centralized method.

This detects programatic events, keyboard events and mouse events

Note that the listener is added to the ToggleGroup

```java
public class ReportOptionsPane extends BorderPane implements ChangeListener<Toggle> {
    RadioButton radioFoldersOnly ;
    RadioButton radioAllItems ;
    RadioButton radioArtifactsOnly  ;
    RadioButton radioStatsOrderByOccurrence  ;
    RadioButton radioStatsOrderByName  ;

    public ReportOptionsPane(ReportOptions rep)  {
        super() ;
        ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
        radioFoldersOnly = new RadioButton("Folders only") ;
        radioAllItems = new RadioButton("Files & Folders") ;
        radioArtifactsOnly = new RadioButton("Artifacts only") ;

        radioFoldersOnly.setToggleGroup(tg);
        radioAllItems.setToggleGroup(tg);
        radioArtifactsOnly.setToggleGroup(tg);

        //You add the listener to the toogle group of your radio buttons
        tg.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(this);

        ToggleGroup tg2 = new ToggleGroup();
        radioStatsOrderByOccurrence = new RadioButton("Order stats by occurrence") ;
        radioStatsOrderByName = new RadioButton("Order stats by name") ;

        radioStatsOrderByOccurrence.setToggleGroup(tg2);
        radioStatsOrderByName.setToggleGroup(tg2);

        //You can reuse the listener for the second toogle group of your radio buttons
        tg2.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(this);
    }

    //Then you handle all in a centralized place 
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable, Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {
        if(newValue.equals(radioFoldersOnly)) {
            //react to radio button being selected
        } else if(newValue.equals(radioAllItems)) {
            //react to radio button being selected
        } else if(newValue.equals(radioArtifactsOnly)) {
            //react to radio button being selected
        } else if(newValue.equals(radioStatsOrderByName)) {
            //react to radio button being selected
        } else if(newValue.equals(radioStatsOrderByOccurrence)  {
            //react to radio button being selected
        }
    }
}
```